# MongoDB GridFS uploads zero-length file when using Node and request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I'm trying to save a file from a URL to a Mongo GridFS file. I'm using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) npm module, and the official mongo driver.

This is my code:

```
function retrieveAttachments(NormalizedMessage) {
NormalizedMessage.attachments.forEach(
  function (currentAttachment) {
    var bucket = new GridFSBucket(db);
    var httpRequestStream = require('request');

    httpRequestStream.get(currentAttachment.url)
      .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .pipe(bucket.openUploadStream('dsa'));

  }
);
```

}

"db" is obtained from MongoClient.connect, and GridFSBucket = require('mongodb').GridFSBucket;

The problem I have is that the file is inserted in mongo (I can see it in the fs.files collection), but it's length is zero.
If i also add a .on('finish') event to the upload stream, it gets called.

If I replace bucket.openUploadStream('dsa') with fs.createWriteStream('someFile'), the HTTP request is saved to someFile in the local filesystem.

If I replace httpRequestStream.get(currentAttachment.url) with fs.createReadStream("test.jpg"), the file test.jpg is successfully uploaded to GridFS.

Comment: *"If i also add a .on('finish') event to the upload stream, it gets called...*" - So I would actually wager that it's **always** being called, but it's simply a timing issue in the rest of your code that does not wait for the `.pipe()` to complete before you are looking. Using `.pipe()` is handy, but it's still all an async operation and you need to wait before you go and look. How exactly are you looking for the created content?

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm also thinking it's a timing issue but I though the pipes would basically wait for each other? as in, the receiving pipe would wait for the sending pipe to send an EOF of sorts?

Comment: I'm not just "thinking it", I'm pointing out the problem. Here you have a defined function `retrieveAttachments()`, which surely your code is calling. It's missing a "callback" which means that whatever context it's being called for is not waiting for the "stream" to complete. You need to do that. If you cannot work it out by yourself, then show the context in which the function gets called and you can be shown what to do.

Comment: I'm not reading the fs.files collection right after I insert them in the database. What I use to see in the tables is a mongo GUI (Robo 3T), much after the files have been inserted. I don't think I need my code to wait for the stream to complete? It will keep running in the background, wouldn't it?

Comment: I am facing the same issue and the problem that Neil is pointing to solve that I have wrapped my upload logic inside a promise. But still have a file with zero length.